# Hash inspection in IRB?

Tags: ruby, hash, irb

I have a hash:

```
hash = { test: 'Test' }
```

If I am in an irb session and I enter `hash`, it outputs the content of the hash:

```
{
  :test => 'Test'
}
```

What method is being invoked on the variable `hash` when I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.inspect
```

The method is usually used for printing object structure.

Comment: Ok, so could I override this then in a subclass of Hash?

Comment: @TheDelChop yes . You can override almost all methods in Ruby.

Comment: `Object#inspect` is the more common way to represent an instance method.

Answer (score 3):

The method is [`Hash#inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-inspect).

```
hash = { test: 'Test' }
# => {:test=>"Test"}

hash.inspect
# => "{:test=>\"Test\"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

IRB calls `#inspect` method on your expressions and prints its result.

Answer (score 2):

When your hash contains a lot of data, it can be painful to read its content in one line.

I like to use `y` that print the hash in yaml.

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
y h
# --- 
#  :b: 2
#  :a: 1
# => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

IRB will call [Hash#inspect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-inspect).

```
hash.inspect
```